# Change UIView of storyboard dynamically and keep the rest of the subviews in place

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

I have a `storyboard` and I am trying to change the `UIView` to set a custom gradient view that I have created.

I have tried `self.view = myNewViewWithGradient;` and the gradient is displayed, but no other element can be seen since I am replacing the current view.

How can I set a new view dynamically and keep the elements that have been added in the storyboard?

I have tried re-adding the subviews (that have a referencing outlet) to this new view, but nothing is displayed.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.txtPassword];
```

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: here is a screenshot of the outlets set in the storyboard:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all your subviews to your new view, something like:

```
[myNewViewWithGradient setFrame:self.view.frame];
for (UIView* v in [self.view subviews]) {
    [myNewViewWithGradient addSubview:v];
}
self.view = myNewViewWithGradient;
```

but I can not see what are you trying to achieve, did you just want a new background? You can do somehting like:

```
[self.view addSubview:myNewViewWithGradient];
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:myNewViewWithGradient];
```

Your `sendSubviewToBack:myNewViewWithGradient` is an `UIView`? If it did not work please provide more information so we can better help you :)

Comment: Both are excellent solutions I didnt think of. Although I am having trouble accesing self.view, even when I call if(self.view != NULL)
        NSLog(@"not null");  xcode goes crazy as if it was stuck in a loop. So I am not able to set the new view with either one of your solutions. Do you know if there are any restrictions when modifying a self.view that is linked to a storyboard? Thanks!

Comment: No, I do not think so, your mistake probably is in another part, are yours outlets properly seted? Also check your storyboard, because from what you posted here, it was supposed to be working.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the outlets set in my storyboard.I believe they are set correctly. myNewViewWithGradient is a UIView. When I do self.view = myNewViewWithGradient it displays correctly, but all the other elements (buttons and txtviews) are gone.

Comment: did you tried the exactly code that I posted here? Adding it before set the self.view ? Can you post some more code ?

Comment: For some reason, after commenting -(void) loadView  even though the function was empty, the code you posted started to work correctly. I don't understand this behaviour, but the bottom line is: it works now! Thanks for your help